# Python Numpy - Merge subarrays with a 4D array, can't get swapaxes working to build a 2D global array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 8x8 array divided into 2x2 blocks, so I have 16 subarrays. The 4 dimensions are (4,4,2,2) : first is row of a block, second its column, the third is the row index of subarray 2x2 and fourth is column index of subarray 2x2.

The 2 first lines of the global array are (2 lines of 8 columns) :

```
[3.28542331e+09 3.28542331e+09 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0]
[0. 0. 2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10 5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10 8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10]
```

I try to get a 8x8 global array from all the 2x2 blocks (16 blocks at total); I did :

```
arrayFullCross.swapaxes(0,2).reshape(8,8)
```

But thi doesn't work. Indeed, the first line is correct but not the second one. here what I got :

```
reshape =  [[3.28542331e+09 3.28542331e+09 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 ...
```

As you can see, the values `5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10`and `8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10`don't appear on the second line.

They appear on the third line :

```
[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10
  1.01028455e+11 1.01028455e+11 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
```

Instead, I would like to get on the second line :

```
 [[3.28542331e+09 3.28542331e+09 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
      0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
     [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10
      5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10 8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10]
```

I want to build a 2D 8x8 array from the 4D array.

### Edit 1

Here below the print of the full 4D array (by doing `print 'arrayFullCross = ', arrayFullCross`) :

```
arrayFullCross =  [[[[3.28542331e+09 3.28542331e+09]
   [8.97951610e+07 8.97951610e+07]]

  [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]]


 [[[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10]
   [7.10926896e+08 7.10926896e+08]]

  [[5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10]
   [1.40108708e+09 1.40108708e+09]]

  [[8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10]
   [2.32314196e+09 2.32314196e+09]]]


 [[[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[1.01028455e+11 1.01028455e+11]
   [2.76124733e+09 2.76124733e+09]]

  [[1.67515243e+11 1.67515243e+11]
   [4.57842318e+09 4.57842318e+09]]]


 [[[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
   [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]]

  [[1.38878482e+11 1.38878482e+11]
   [3.79574089e+09 3.79574089e+09]]]]
```

### Edit 2

OK, the way I have to check if reshape is well done is :

```
  print 'shape(arrayFull = ', np.shape(arrayFullCross)

  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 0 = ', arrayFullCross[0][0][0][0:2] 
  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 1 = ', arrayFullCross[0][1][0][0:2] 
  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 2 = ', arrayFullCross[0][2][0][0:2] 
  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 3 = ', arrayFullCross[0][3][0][0:2] 
  print ' '
  print 'here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 0 = ', arrayFullCross[1][0][0][0:2] 
  print 'here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 1 = ', arrayFullCross[1][1][0][0:2] 
  print 'here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 2 = ', arrayFullCross[1][2][0][0:2] 
  print 'here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 3 = ', arrayFullCross[1][3][0][0:2] 
  print ' '
  print 'test all  first line  , arrayFullCross column = 0,1,2,3 = ', arrayFullCross[0][0:4][0][0:2] 
  print ' '
  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 1 = ', arrayFullCross[0][1][0][0:2] 
  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 2 = ', arrayFullCross[0][2][0][0:2] 
  print 'here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 3 = ', arrayFullCross[0][3][0][0:2]
```

which gives :

```
shape(arrayFull =  (4, 4, 2, 2)
here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 0 =  [3.28542331e+09 3.28542331e+09]
here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 1 =  [0. 0.]
here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 2 =  [0. 0.]
here first line  , arrayFullCross column = 3 =  [0. 0.]
 
here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 0 =  [0. 0.]
here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 1 =  [2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10]
here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 2 =  [5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10]
here second line  , arrayFullCross column = 3 =  [8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10]
```

But I have doubts about this printing of the 2 first lines all along the column index (second `index j` in `arrayFullCross[i][j][k][l]`.

Unfortunately, the **almost solution** with `print 'reshape = ', arrayFullCross.swapaxes(2,0).reshape(8,8)` gives :

```
reshape =  [[3.28542331e+09 3.28542331e+09 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10
  1.01028455e+11 1.01028455e+11 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10
  1.67515243e+11 1.67515243e+11 1.38878482e+11 1.38878482e+11]
 [8.97951610e+07 8.97951610e+07 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 7.10926896e+08 7.10926896e+08
  0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 1.40108708e+09 1.40108708e+09
  2.76124733e+09 2.76124733e+09 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.32314196e+09 2.32314196e+09
  4.57842318e+09 4.57842318e+09 3.79574089e+09 3.79574089e+09]]
```

From my printing, the second line should be instead equal to :

```
[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 2.60113771e+10 2.60113771e+10
      5.12629421e+10 5.12629421e+10 8.49990653e+10 8.49990653e+10]
```

Is it possible to use swapaxes multiple times ?

Comment: What is `arrayFullCross.swapaxes(0,2).shape`?

Comment: @hpaulj `arrayFullCross` is the 4D array referencing by `arrayFullCross[i][j][k][l]` with `i`the line of block, `j`, its columns, `k`the line of element into subarray and `l`its position in columns.

Comment: I want to see the shape tuple.  I don't want an explanation.

Comment: @hpaulj you can see the full array into **EDIT 1**, thanks

Comment: I don't need to see the whole array!!!  I asking you to verify for yourself whether the `swap` is doing what you think it should.  Let me put it more directly, you are using the wrong swap parameters.  That should be obvious if you look at the resulting shape!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess my comments weren't clear enough.

```
In [811]: arr = np.ones((4,4,2,2),int)
In [812]: arr.swapaxes(0,2).shape
Out[812]: (2, 4, 4, 2)
```

Yes, that can be reshaped to (8,8), but there's bound to be some sort of transposition, since one pair of dimensions is (2,4) and the other (4,2).

If you had swapped axes to produce a (2,4,2,4) or (4,2,4,2) I expect the reshape will be right.

The exact details of which swap is right depends on how you want to arange the subblocks.  Hopefully you can track those?

---

Make a simple array with nice (2,2) blocks:

```
In [813]: arr = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [815]: arr1 =np.tile(arr[None,None,:,:],(4,4,1,1))
In [816]: arr1.shape
Out[816]: (4, 4, 2, 2)

In [817]: arr1
Out[817]: 
array([[[[0, 1],
         [2, 3]],

        [[0, 1],
         [2, 3]],
   ...
```

Look at what different swaps produce:

```
In [822]: arr1.swapaxes(0,2).reshape(8,8)
Out[822]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]])
In [823]: 
In [823]: arr1.swapaxes(1,3).reshape(8,8)
Out[823]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
In [824]: arr1.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(8,8)
Out[824]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]])
```

The one that works produces a (4,2,4,2) shape:

```
In [825]: arr1.swapaxes(0,2).shape
Out[825]: (2, 4, 4, 2)
In [826]: arr1.swapaxes(1,3).shape
Out[826]: (4, 2, 2, 4)
In [827]: arr1.swapaxes(1,2).shape
Out[827]: (4, 2, 4, 2)
```

and another swap

```
In [829]: arr1.swapaxes(0,3).shape
Out[829]: (2, 4, 2, 4)
In [830]: arr1.swapaxes(0,3).reshape(8,8)
Out[830]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: @hpaujj . That did the trick ! good 2D array with `arrayFullCross.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(8,8)` . Thanks a lot